# Styled Components Color Picker not showing

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, visual-studio-code, styled-components

I've been using VSCode with React and Styled Components for about 6 months--no issues. Recently, the color picker hasn't been showing up when including any CSS properties involving color. A quick reload of the window or restarting VScode would always solve this issue..until now. I've changed the selected language to CSS, Javascript, Javascript React, and CSS (Styled Components). Nothing works.

I've tried uninstalling/re-installing styled components extensions. Nothing. I uninstalled and reinstalled VSCode, but that also didn't work.

I have this extension installed
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=styled-components.vscode-styled-components

[Image of color picker not showing up next to color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jteis.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT: For anyone that might run into this in the future, installing this extension fixes the issue.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AntiAntiSepticeye.vscode-color-picker

Comment: Can you include some of your respective configurations? Sometimes tinkering with the settings will pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Any settings in particular? I haven't really messed with any settings. I think the only thing I've changed from default is allowing emmet to recognize 'javascriptreact' and I did that long before having this problem

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into the question. Add an answer instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default the VSCode will enable color picker for stylesheet files such as `.css`, `.less`, `.scss` and `.sass`

In order to have the color picker for other file types, wherever there is an valid HEX tag, also to make the valid answer more complete, there are two steps to follow,

1. install extension [vscode-color-picker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AntiAntiSepticeye.vscode-color-picker).
2. add following to the `seetings.json` of your VSCode, since by default it enables for `[python,javascript,typescript]`

```rb
"vscode-color-picker.languages": [
"php",
"html",
"css",
"python",
"jsonc",
"javascript",
"javascriptreact",
"typescript",
"typescriptreact",
"vue"
]
```

Comment: how about react-native and jsx files? it does not work to me at least with react-native jsx files.

Comment: thats what im talking about! thank you! the color picker wasnt showing up for me either but this solution really helped out!